# Recover formated Linux Mint encrypted Drive

Tags: linux, linux-mint, encryption, disk-encryption, restore

When installing Windows 10 I accidentally mixed the drives and deleted another one that had Linux Mint and was encrypted, since then I haven't done anything on drive to not overwrite anything. Is it possible to recover it somehow as it was before or only by restore software that will restore only files.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr version: I hope you have a backup, because chance to recover the data is very low.

If you only formatted the disk to NTFS you might still be able to recover the data, but it might be not possible. "Problem" with encrypted devices is that if you loose the LUKS metadata with the encryption key, you won't be able to recover the data because everything is encrypted and you just deleted/overwrote the key stored in the metadata (keyslot) area.

There usually will be an unencrypted `/boot` partition at the start of the disk with encrypted Linux installation so you still have chance to recover the data because Windows probably overwrote only the partition table and start of the first partition.

You'll need to locate start of the LUKS encrypted partition on the disk (you should look for LUKS superblock `4c 55 4b 53 ba be`), create new partition table on the disk and a partition starting on the location of the LUKS superblock and after you should be able open the device using `cryptsetup`. But if Windows overwrote the header or keyslot area it wouldn't be possible to recover the data.

You should make a copy of the disk before doing anything with it and if possible work with the image first and not with the disk to avoid accidentally overwriting more of it.

Comment: I dont have any experience on the recovery area, only did once with EASE US, Is there any professional I can contact ( Pay also ) to help me backup the disk as it is so I dont mess it up more and help me with other stuff or can you?